# Webform confirmation message replacing my webform block while using webform_ajax

Tags: ajax, webforms

i have made a contact webform and i want to submit it using ajax,for that i used web_form ajax.
In the settings i selected "show all the messages in the same webform block "
But the thing i want is that i want to show the confirmation message in the webform block but don't want it to replace my contact form.
Or is there a way that i can show confirmation message on the same page in a pop-up window using when the webform is submitted